# Getter Block execution without VF reference

Tags: apex, attribute

My understanding of the Getter Setter is that getter is invoked if the particular variable is being referenced in VF Page.

However for the following code I see that Getter is getting called even if no variable reference is on the page.

```
    public class EmbeddedTest
    {
       public list<account> lAcc{
       get{
           system.debug('INSIDE GETTER');
           return null;
       }
       set;
       }

       public void checkChanges()
       {
          lAcc=[select id,name from account limit 10];
          system.debug('ACCOUNT LOG GENERATED '+lAcc);
       }
    }
```

VF Page:

```
<apex:page controller="EmbeddedTest">
  <apex:form >
     <apex:commandButton action="{!checkChanges}"  value="Click to change!"/>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

On clicking the button I see the below logs(in order):

> 08:37:22.0 (14537986)|SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN|[19]|Aggregations:0|SELECT
>   id, name FROM account LIMIT 10
>
> 08:37:22.0 (19987384)|SOQL_EXECUTE_END|[19]|Rows:10
>
> 08:37:22.0 (20434238)|USER_DEBUG|[3]|DEBUG|INSIDE GETTER
>
> 08:37:22.0 (20537127)|USER_DEBUG|[20]|DEBUG|ACCOUNT LOG GENERATED null

**Why does the Getter get called and make the list(lAcc) null even without any VF reference ?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You call the getter here:

```
system.debug('ACCOUNT LOG GENERATED '+lAcc);
```

Accessing the attribute value of `lAcc` in any way calls the getter.

Comment: Okay. So does it mean that manipulation of lAcc(eg, the SOQL result assignment) will have no bearing on the value of lAcc. It will always return what the getter block returns.

Comment: It will always return what the getter block returns, yes. Assigning a value only calls the setter and doesn't call the getter unless you try to access the variable.